# How often is garbage collected?

Tags: javascript, browser, garbage-collection

If I understand correctly the GC works like this:

```
MyClass.prototype.render = function(){
    var largeArray = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        largeArray.push({
            firstName: 'John',
            lastName: 'Smith'
        });
    }
}
```

When `render()` is called, `largeArray` is marked for garbage collection but not immediately collected.

I am curious because I have a lockscreen widget for my phone. It's a browser that shows a HTML page on lockscreen. It works so every time I load my lockscreen the widget is reloaded.

Problem is, every ~5th time I open lockscreen the phone reboots to safe mode. It seems when I unlock the phone the widget browser is closed before garbage collection can run. Does it sound right?

[Here's my widget.](http://joakim1.gear.host/feed/) In console it outputs the size of the major objects.

Comment: GC is implementation dependent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management), your problem is not in garbage collector, i think that somewere in your code there is variables that is created and located in the memory and never released, review thees links for js best practices

[[1] JavaScript Best Practices](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)

[[2] OOP in JS](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_best_practices.asp)

Comment: **"somewere in your code there is variables that is created and located in the memory and never released"* - That's what the GC is for.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: Perhaps poor wording but what he means is: "somewhere in your code the memory is still being referenced so they're never garbage collected". Among programmers who program in languages that have garbage collection built-in this is usually referred to "never released" because it's implicit what "never released" means.